# Order grouped values differently in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

```
select 
  source_of_data,
  convert(varchar(10),a.DATECREATED,101),
  COUNT(*)
from some_table a
group by
  source_of_data, 
  convert(varchar(10),a.DATECREATED,101)
order by 
  source_of_data,
  convert(varchar(10),a.DATECREATED,101)
```

Output data looks like this:

```
mainframe 4/5/11  22
mainframe 4/6/11  45
mainframe n/n/nn  nn
sqlserver 4/5/11  44
sqlserver 4/6/11  67
sqlserver n/n/nn  nn
```

But I want the output to look like this:

```
mainframe 4/5/11  22
sqlserver 4/5/11  44
mainframe 4/6/11  45
sqlserver 4/6/11  67
mainframe n/n/nn  nn
sqlserver n/n/nn  nn
```

This way I can easily verify visually if a grouped entry for any particular date is missing—say for some day we get mainframe data but sqlserver data is missing. Can someone please help modify the query so I don't have to resort to writing a stored proc to achieve my objective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, just switch your order by to

```
convert(Date, a.DATECREATED,101), source_of_data
```

then your results should come out how you describe

Edit: converting it to varchar, it will not work as expected. Convert it to DATE type.

Comment: No prob, we all have those days

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
  select 
      source_of_data,
      convert(varchar(10),a.DATECREATED,101),
      COUNT(*)
    from some_table a
    group by
      source_of_data, 
      convert(varchar(10),a.DATECREATED,101)
    order by 
     COUNT(*)
```